# Define a custom command with name, label and linkable

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing

I'd like to create a command with the following features:

```
\newcommand{\mycom}[2]{...}
\newcommand{\linktomycom}[1]{...}
```

In the doc body:

```
\mycom{firstitem}{This is the first item}
```

and later:

```
\linktomycom{firstitem}
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
\hyperref[firstitem]{This is the first item}
```

and link to the position where I wrote `\mycom`.

...

I played around with phantomsec, but it seems to miss a naming feature. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Why don't you use `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`?

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, I was missing these two commands, which bring the question a step further. There is still the problem: if I define
\hyperlink{label}{my nice caption}

I'd like to be able to write something like:
\hypertarget{label}
which should then be rendered as a clickable "my nice caption"

this is not possible directly, as the caption field for \hyperlink is mandatory

Comment: (I switched hyperlink and hypertarget in the comment above)

Answer (score 3):

The commands could be defined like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycom}[2]{\hypertarget{#1}{#2}\global\@namedef{mycom@#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\linktomycom}[1]{%
\@ifundefined{mycom@#1}{\textbf{??}\@latex@warning{Reference `#1' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
{\hyperlink{#1}{\@nameuse{mycom@#1}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

`\mycom{...}{...}` creates a target named like the first argument with the text of the second argument and saves the caption in the macro `\mycom@<first argument>`.

`\linktomycom{...}` checks if `\mycom@<first argument>` is defined - if it isn't,  two question marks and a LaTeX warning are produced, otherwise, a link to the specified target with the previously saved text is generated.

(The definitions are enclosed in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` because internal LaTeX macros with an `@` in their name are used.)

#### EDIT:

I couldn't find out if you want the `\mycom` command to produce a visible caption or just an (invisible) anchor - if you want the latter, you must define a target with an empty text:

```
\newcommand{\mycom}[2]{\hypertarget{#1}{}\@namedef{mycom@#1}{#2}}
```